# MySQL query takes long to execute if using ORDER BY String Column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, query-optimization

So my query on a table that contains `4 million` records executes instant if I dont use `order by`. However I want to give my clients a way to sort results by `Name` field and only show last `100` of the filtered result. As soon as I add `order by Name` it takes 100 seconds to execute.

My table structure is similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Name VARCHAR(100),
   StatusID INT,
   KEY (StatusID), <-- Index on StatusID
   KEY (StatusID, Name) <-- Index on StatusID, Name
   KEY(Name) <-- Index on Name
);
```

My query simply does something like:

```
explain SELECT ID, StatusID, Name
FROM Test
WHERE StatusID = 113
ORDER BY Name DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Above explain when I order by `Name` gives this result:

[image]

`StatusID_2` is the composite index of `StatausID, Name`

Now If I change `ORDER BY Name DESC` to `ORDER BY ID` I get this:
[image]

How can I make it so that it also examines only `100` rows when using `ORDER BY Name`?

Comment: Have you run `EXPLAIN` on the queries to see how the query plans differ?

Comment: @cdhowie updated my answer. The one with order by looks through 3.8 million rows which I know the problem but how do I fix it. I still need it to be ordered.

Comment: Very odd indeed, I would expect it to use the index on `Name`. What happens if you do the ordering and limit prior to the join? (`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Test WHERE StatusID = 12 ORDER BY Name DESC LIMIT 0, 100) t JOIN ...`, and using `t` instead of `Test` in the join clauses.)

Comment: @cdhowie i tried something similar but results were same.

Comment: @cdhowie joins are not problem. In explain joins only go through 1 row. 3.8 Million rows are from Test table which is the main table.

Comment: @cdhowie the strangest thing is, if I add `order by id` it is also 100 rows in explain. so `order by Name` or any non integer type messes up the speed

Comment: I assume based on your question that there is in fact an index on the Name column?

Comment: @cdhowie yes I have index on Name column.

Comment: So where is `EXPLAIN`? PS: it's obvious that a dedicated index on `Name` won't help isn't it? It's also obvious that "joins are not problem" statement is just wrong.

Comment: I'm wondering if a composite index on `(StatusID, Name)` would make a difference.

Comment: @zerkms I'm not answering. I'm commenting.

Comment: Yep. That's my point :-) And as soon as new comments arrive - OP would continue discussion instead of providing `EXPLAN` + complete schema + statistics :-)

Comment: @zerkms I updated my question. Please look at it.

Comment: @GGio: for the provided question you indeed need a composite index like cdhowie mentioned before. But it does not mean that the other query will be optimized the same way. So when you are trying to optimize a particular query - you need to provide an `EXPLAIN` for that query, not for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing, try for letters which would be in 100 rows expected in result like

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
*** Some Joins to filter data or get more columns from other tables
WHERE StatusID = 12 AND NAME REGEXP '^[A-H]'
ORDER BY Name DESC
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Moreover using index is very important on name (which is already applied) – in this case index range scan will be started and query execution stopped as soon as soon as required amount of rows generated.

So we can't use ID for nothing as it won't scan when it has reached its limit, the only thing we can try for is remove letters which are not possible in expected result and this what we are trying to do with REGEXP

Comment: Updated my question please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without the joins and the explain result but you're not making use of index appeareantly.

It might be because of the joins or because you have another key in the where clause. I'd recommend reading this, it covers all possible cases: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Increasing the `sort_buffer_size` and/or `read_rnd_buffer_size` might help...

Comment: Can you try this: `select id,statusid,name from test use index(name) where statusid=5 order by name limit 5;`

Answer (score 0):

You need a composite key based on the filtering WHERE criteria PLUS the order by... create an index on

( StatusID, Name )

This way, the WHERE jumps right to your StatusID = 12 records and ignores the rest of the 4 million... THEN uses the name as a secondary to qualify the ORDER BY.

Without seeing the other tables / join criteria and associated indexes, you might also want to try adding MySQL keyword

SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ... rest of query

So it does the query in the order you have selected, but unsure of impact without seeing other joins as noted previously.

ADDITION (per feedback)

I would remove the individual indexes on the ID only so the engine doesn't have to guess which one to use.  The composite index can be used as an ID only query regardless of the name so you don't need to have both.

Also, remove the Name only index UNLESS you will ever be querying PRIMARILY on the name as a where qualifier without the ID qualifier... Also, how many total records are even possible for the example IDs you are querying out of the 4 million...  You MIGHT want to pull the full set for the id as a sub-query, get a few thousand and have THAT ordered by name which would be quick... something like...

```
select *
   from ( SELECT 
                ID, 
                StatusID, 
                Name
             FROM 
                Test
             WHERE 
                StatusID = 113 ) PreQuery
   ORDER BY 
      Name DESC
   LIMIT 0, 100
```

Comment: An important note: this answer is based on assumption that mysql did not reorder joins

Comment: @DRapp Updated my question please look at it.

Comment: @DRapp i did that and now it examines 3.8 Million rows * 2. One for derived table. :(

Comment: @GGio, makes no sense unless you have 3.8 million rows with status = 113

Comment: @DRapp yes there are 3.8 million rows with status 113

Comment: @GGio, in your original query, you mentioned other tables/joins/criteria and your query came back almost instantaneously.  Could some of those other criteria be a smaller set to what you are looking for and THAT becomes a basis of final query?  Editing your post with that data might help other avenues.